# Random number being changed within Python script

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm working on a Python script where a user has to guess a random number, selected by the script. This is my code:

```
import random
while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 3)
    print("Can you guess the right number?")
    antwoord = input("Enter a number between 1 and 3: ")
    if antwoord == number:
        print ("Dang, that's the correct number!")
        print (" ")
    else:
       print ("Not the same!")
       print ("The correct answer is:")
       print (number)

    while True:
        answer = input('Try again? (y/n): ')
        print (" ")
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("You can only answer with y or n!")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Better next time!")
        break
```

It works... Sort of... I was trying it and came across this:
[User enters 2, it says it's incorrect, but then displays the same number!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8x46.png)

I have the feeling that, every time I call the variable 'number', it changes the random number again. How can I force the script to hold the random number picked at the beginning, and not keep changing it within the script?

Comment: why not assign the random number outside while?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? If it is python 3, you need to evaluate the input (using ```eval(input())```) - ```"2"``` is not the same as ```2```

Comment: If that's the case @AhsanulHaque , How do you explain it says it's the wrong number, but later displays the same number and says that was the right number to be chosen?

Comment: Input returns a string, can't equal a number : '2' != 2. Try int (input))

Comment: It's Python 3 @Lolgast So I'll try your solution!

Comment: In each loop, if you calling `random.randint(1, 3)`, it does change. But, calling `number` variable, it doesn't change.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the solution @GBy I'll try it out!

Comment: There was some confusion about whether or not you want to pick a new random number for every iteration of the loop. Can you clearly state if this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you want to pick a new random integer in every loop step. 
I guess you are using python 3 and  so `input` returns a string. Since you cannot perform comparisson between a string and an int, you need to convert the input string to an int first.

```
import random
while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 3)
    print("Can you guess the right number?")
    antwoord = input("Enter a number between 1 and 3: ")
    try:
        antwoord = int(antwoord)
    except:
        print ("You need to type in a number")
    if antwoord == number:
        print ("Dang, that's the correct number!")
        print (" ")
    else:
       print ("Not the same!")
       print ("The correct answer is:")
       print (number)

    while True:
        answer = input('Try again? (y/n): ')
        print (" ")
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("You can only answer with y or n!")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Better next time!")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution!